# Main thread hanging at queue join because q.get() on empty queue does not return

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a request manager that builds a queue and starts `x` worker threads (`x` currently == 1).
Each thread is looping and getting elements from the queue appending the results to a shared list.
If the queue is exhausted the `queue.Empty` exception is caught, the current job marked as done and the thread should exit. This does work.

This block at the end of the `run()` however seems to break things. The queue has an arbitrary length and it might occur that the queue is longer then actual results fetchable. In order to exit  all threads early a thread checks if the result he got has `len == 0`. If this is the case the thread clears the queue of all items left, marks itself as done and exits.

```py
if len(request_result) == 0:
    with self.q.mutex:
        self.q.queue.clear()
        self.q.task_done()
        return
```

My assumption was that every thread would then finish it's current job and exit.
However the execution of the main thread hangs at `q.join()` and I can't debug why. From the debugger it looks like the worker-thread is not terminating. But that's just guessing.

I've read: [Threading queue hangs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810172/threading-queue-hangs-in-python)
but that does not solve the problem. I however set `q.unfinished_tasks` to 0 manually but that is not thread safe and will cause the program to crash when threads try to call `taks_done()` when another thread just set `q.unfinished_tasks` to 0.

```py
class RequestManager:
    def __init__(self, config=None):
        self.config = config

    def request_all_heroes(self):
        q = queue.Queue()
        result_list = []
        #  todo: get range max from highest hero ID.
        for skip in [x * 100 for x in range(1, 3)]:
            q.put_nowait(skip)

        for _ in range(int(self.config["meta"]["number_of_threads"])):
            RequestWorker(q=q,
                          config=self.config,
                          query_name='all_heroes',
                          shared_result_list=result_list).start()
        q.join()
        return [Hero(item) for sublist in result_list for item in sublist]

class RequestWorker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,
                 q=None,
                 config=None,
                 query_name="",
                 shared_result_list=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.q = q
        self.config = config
        self.query_file_path = self.config["files"][query_name]
        self.shared_result_list = shared_result_list
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        keep_running = True
        while keep_running:
            try:
                skip_number = self.q.get()
            except queue.Empty:
                self.q.task_done()
                return

            sr = SpecificRequest(config=self.config, skip=skip_number, query_file_path=self.query_file_path)
            request_result = sr.do_specific_request()

            if len(request_result) == 0:
                with self.q.mutex:
                    self.q.queue.clear()
                    self.q.task_done()
                    return

            self.shared_result_list.append(request_result)
            self.q.task_done()
```

***EDIT 1***

```py
            if not self.q.empty():
                skip_number = self.q.get()
            else:
                return
```

This works, unfortunately it is plain wrong becase `get` is called after the check if the queue is empty. This will cause problems at some point because a thread can check, see an element in the queue and another thread can snatch that last element in the meantime. Unlikely but possible.

This question is now about why `self.q.get()` does not return.

Comment: Ob some further digging it looks like the queue.Empty exception is not raised by the code hence the worker thread never exits and the program does not terminate.

Comment: A call of self.queue.get() on an empty queue does not return:
https://i.imgur.com/OsJVP6K.png